# Wildfly Reverse Proxy Response.sendRedirect is not working

Tags: java, wildfly, reverse-proxy, undertow

I am trying to create a reverse proxy for my JAVA application (run on Wildfly-10.1.0).

http://localhost:8181/DDDD/
will point to 
http://localhost:8080/XXXX/

These are the changes I include in the standalone.xml (port 8181)

PART 1:

```
<location name="/DDDD" handler="wf2-proxy"/>
```

PART 2:

```
<reverse-proxy name="wf2-proxy">
                <host name="wf2" instance-id="wf2-route" path="/XXXX" outbound-socket-binding="wf2-binding"/>
            </reverse-proxy>
```

PART 3:

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="wf2-binding">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="8080"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
```

I having problem during redirect response

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL("AAA/rrr.jsp?Flag=d"));
```

It did not redirect to rrr.jsp after this line.

Can anyone guide here?

Comment: Did you get this straightened out?  I'm also trying to do the reveres-proxy but over https and it's failing, I've followed numerous documents and I recognize your code from one of the examples.  You're question on this `response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL("AAA/rrr.jsp?Flag=d"));` is a little strange though or possibly misunderstanding.

Comment: Hi JGlass,
Sorry for late reply. I success do http with these configuration on wildfly.
For example 
192.168.0.1:7070/APP_FAKE to 192.168.0.2:8080/APP

<location name="/APP_FAKE" handler="wf2-proxy"/>

<reverse-proxy name="wf2-proxy">
                    <host name="wf2-binding" scheme="http" path="/APP" instance-id="wf2-route" outbound-socket-binding="wf2-binding"/>
                </reverse-proxy>

<outbound-socket-binding name="wf2-binding">
            <remote-destination host="192.168.0.2" port="8080"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>

Comment: If not mistaken, you just need to change scheme to https
scheme="https"

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try it out when I get some time!  Thanks again for taking the time to reply!